# How to use ModelCheckpoint with custom metrics in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Is it possible to use custom [metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/) in the [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) callback?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Define the custom metrics as described in the documentation:

```
import keras.backend as K

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred])
```

To check all available metrics:

```
print(model.metrics_names)
> ['loss', 'acc', 'mean_pred']
```

Pass the metric name to `ModelCheckpoint` through `monitor`. If you want the metric calculated in the validation, use the `val_` prefix.

```
ModelCheckpoint(weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_mean_pred:.2f}.hdf5,
                monitor='val_mean_pred',
                save_best_only=True,
                save_weights_only=True,
                mode='max',
                period=1)
```

Don't use `mode='auto'` for custom metrics. Understand why [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L366-L378).

---

*Why am I answering my own question? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).*

Comment: Link for understand why is broken. Got me curious

Comment: I got why. When you build a custom model ModelCheckpoint doesn't know if higher or lower value is better, so mode='auto' is bad. In my case, I defined F1 metric, so I needed to tell ModelCheckpoint that a higher value val_f1 is better, so mode='max'.