# Keras: Rename Metrics for Same Tensorboard Graph Viewing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, tensorboard

Use Case:
I have multiple models each with a slightly different architecture.  Model A with one output and Model B with two outputs (call them `output_1` and `output_2`).  `output_1` of Model B corresponds to the same information as the single output of Model A.  I would like plot the accuracies/losses from `output_1` of Model B together with those of Model A on the same graph in Tensorboard.  I'm using the functional layer protocols for Models A/B and hence given the two outputs of Model B names: `output_1`, `output_2` while giving the output of Model A: `output_1`.

I've noticed Keras/Tensorboard will report the accuracies/losses for Model B as `output_1_acc, output_2_acc, output_1_loss, output_2_loss, val_output_1_acc, val_output_2_acc, val_output_1_loss, val_output_2_loss` (with maybe a `loss` metric name added in that corresponds to the addition of losses from outputs 1/2).  However, I've noticed Keras/Tensorboard will report the accuracies/losses under Model A (if compiled with metric: `accuracy`) as `acc, loss, val_acc, val_loss`.  So the accuracies for `output_1` of Model A/B aren't plotted on the same graph in Tensorboard.  Leaving me to have to download csv's for each and then plot them together manually.

So I'm looking for a clean way to simply rename the metrics (accuracies/losses) for the single output in Model A (`output_1`) so that Tensorboard will report them on the same graphs as the accuracies/losses for output_1 of Model B.

Googling around has given me a method, but it's a bit cumbersome.  Essentially, I have to define custom metrics for Model A with functional names equal to the accuracy/loss names reported for Model B (explicitly referenced in second paragraph above).  And then I compile these custom metrics with the model.
So a brief example of what I'm doing:

```
Class Model_A():

    def edge_output_acc(self, y_true=None, y_pred=None):
        # effectively hardcodes the binary accuracy as form of accuracy
        return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)))


    def edge_output_loss(self, y_true=None, y_pred=None):
        # effectively hardcodes the binary crossentropy as form of loss
        return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

    #now compile with something like this
    def new_compile(self, loss, sgd):
       # loss param could get out of sync with the hardcoded loss unless I recreate a lot of Kera's internal switching
       model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=sgd, metrics=[self.edge_output_acc, self.edge_output_loss])

    #...instead of compiling with something like this
    def old_compile(self, loss, sgd):
        model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

This is fine, except that it forces me to hardcode loss/accuracy type used for Model A (so that I can define these custom metrics).  I would like to provide these as parameters to my model definition script so that modeling is more customizable.  But as I see it this means essentially I have to reproduce Keras' source switching behavior in links [Keras training.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d8b226f26b35348d934edb1213061993e7e5a1fa/keras/engine/training.py#L651)/[Keras metrics.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/c2e36f369b411ad1d0a40ac096fe35f73b9dffd3/keras/metrics.py) from below, which obviously is a headache and redundant.

Is there a cleaner way?

Thanks!

For reference, these links describe the approach I'm currently using and that I describe above, in more detail:

[How to use ModelCheckpoint with custom metrics in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782409/how-to-use-modelcheckpoint-with-custom-metrics-in-keras)

[How does keras define “accuracy” and “loss”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531695/how-does-keras-define-accuracy-and-loss)

[Keras training.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d8b226f26b35348d934edb1213061993e7e5a1fa/keras/engine/training.py#L651)

[Keras metrics.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/c2e36f369b411ad1d0a40ac096fe35f73b9dffd3/keras/metrics.py)

[Keras usage of metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/)

[Keras usage of losses](https://keras.io/losses/)

Comment: So you want for Tensorboard to plot both losses, etc. on the same graph? How are you currently passing that to Tensorboard to plot it in separate graphs?

Comment: You should check out Losswise, it's similar to Tensorboard, it integrates with Keras super easily (https://docs.losswise.com/#keras-plugin) and makes it trivial to do things like viewing multiple graphs on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur I understand well your situation.

For me you just have to make a correct tree directory structure with your log output to to do it and then launch Tensorboard from root folder.

Example: consider \ as root, if you log you loss data from Model A on a folder named model_A and loss from model B on folder named model_B

- \
- \model_A

  - \model_A\output1
- \model_B

  - \model_B\output1
  - \model_B\output2

If you launch Tensorboard from \ you will get each loss on the same display.

Anyway, you can redefine behaviour of the default Tensorboard callback to suit your needs.
Regards